# Switch from Internet Explorer to Edge Chromium / Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, microsoft-edge, ssl-certificate, styles

I'm working on a legacy application created with HTML 4 and PHP 5, my purpose is to run the application on Edge chromium, the style of the application is good on internet explorer but when I tried to run the application on google chrome I see some style problem.

The application on internet explorer

[image]

The application on google chrome (with some style problem)

[image]

For now I can run the application on Chrome, but I cannot run it on edge chromium because I get the error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

How can I run the application on edge even with invalid certificate?

Why the style on Chrome and Internet Explorer is different, and the style on edge chromium will be like Chrome or Internet Explorer?

Comment: Chromium is basically Chrome, so it will look similar to Chrome.

Comment: Why run it with an invalid certificate? Better to create a valid certificate

Comment: even with invalid caertificat I can run the application on Chrome I just want to run the application on edge

Comment: For Edge, try enforcing the site to use Edge's `IE mode` via its [site list XML file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-site-list-manager).  This may show you the old IE page allowing access to the insecure site, depending upon how your group policies are configured/enforced.

Comment: If Edge is showing an invalid certificate message, then the certificate hasn't been installed, in the correct folder/store within Certificate Manager. `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` suggests the Root CA isn't trusted or has been installed in the correct store within the certificate store for the user and/or machine.